# Synchronization in android game loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I'm reading about some android basic game techniques for learning purposes.

I came across some code that synchronizes the access to the SurfaceHolder object used on the game loop thread, why is this necessary?

Sample code found in *sdk/samples/android-18/legacy/LunarLander*, `LunarView.LunarThread` class:

```
public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) updatePhysics();
                    synchronized (mRunLock) {
                        if (mRun) doDraw(c);
                    }
                }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this piece of code gets access to the canvas from the mSurfaceHolder object, which is then locked while the canvas is being drawn on.
Why is the synchronization necessary?

I think it's not, since the only thread requesting the canvas and drawing on it is the thread where the game loop runs.

Also [the documnetation of SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29) says that it will aquire an internal lock until the unlockCanvasAndPost() is called, then why the extra synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the reference you gave, the full quote is:

> If null is not returned, this function internally holds a lock until the corresponding unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas) call, **preventing SurfaceView from creating, destroying, or modifying the surface** while it is being drawn.

My emphasis - note that reading is not in the list.

So `lockCanvas` does not stop it being read from. I would guess the extra synchronization is intended to ensure that other threads are not reading from it at the time - which makes sense because you are calling `updatePhysics` which could be rather upsetting for other readers.

Comment: Ok, I understand the read-lock part, but `updatePhysics` is called from the same thread, the same thread where the drawing is made, so there cannot be a concurrent access to the `mSurfaceHolder`. I still don't get the point.

Comment: It is often difficult to discern the intent of the programmer when their synchronization is examined. It is usually the case that the programmer is defending against obscure races that can only happen when the user is doing something stupid. The only real objection to "too much locking" is if the result is slow and this is unlikely to be a problem in this case. In short - I'd say this is paranoid (but harmlessly so) coding.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the rest of the source code, a number of other operations outside of the SurfaceView thread are also synchronized on `mSurfaceHolder`. My belief therefore is that `mSurfaceHolder` is being used as a convenient 'lock' object to synchronize state between the thread and the rest of the application.